# Bulk Insert multiple tabs - from multiple table export

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have exported data from multiple tables in SQL to an excel spreadsheet.

The method to BULK INSERT from one of these tabs into an existing table in another database is straightforward.

But, how would I BULK INSERT multiple tabs in the excel spreadsheet into each of their corresponding tables in the database?

Each table has a different column structure. 
Each table already exists in the destination database.

Comment: Use SSIS to do this

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=LLF-W83uKuuw0PEPxNeDyA8&q=sql+server+import+multiple+sheets+from+excel+file&oq=sql+server+import+multiple+sheets+from+excel&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.35i39l2j0i22i30.4754.5486..8567...0.0..0.201.387.0j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.ry4yizlGsN4